# Connect a Time Ingelligence Filter to Scorecard's Current Date -- is it possible?

Tags: reporting-services, performancepoint, kpi, dashboard-designer

In PerformancePoint 2013, there's two types of Time Filters -- Time Intelligence, and Time Intelligence Connection Formula. The latter lets me connect the filter's "Current Time" property with a Scorecard's "Current Time", while the Time Intelligence Filter doesn't have that option.

The reason I want to connect to the Current Time of the KPI/Scorecard, is because I already have Time Intelligence Filters applied inside the KPI's Data Mappings. Basically, I'm comparing one set of numbers to the year's previous. I've already tried connecting the Time Intelligence filter's Formula property to the formula property of the KPI, but it just overwrote it.

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

in the formula you can use ie. `day`, for current date and `day-1` for yesterday comparison value

for the complete syntax see:

[PerformancePoint Time Intelligence quick reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701696.aspx)